# How many permutations are there of the letters of the word AARDVARK? In how many of the permutations are the A's separated?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many permutations are there of the letters of the word AARDVARK? In how many of the permutations are the A's separated?

I got answer for the first part of the question, but for the second part I am getting a wrong answer. My answer for the first part goes like this: There are 3 A's and 2 R's in the word AARDVARK and there are totally 8 letters, by using the formula for number of arrangements for $n$ things, $p$ of one kind and $q$ of one kind and $r$ of another kind (formula is $\frac{n!}{p!q!r!\ldots}$) I get the answer to the first part as $\frac{8!}{2!3!} = 28 \cdot 5!=3360$. I need answer for the second part.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What was your answer for the first part?  How did you attempt the second part?

Comment: Think of stars and bars where the letters $A$ function as bars. On left and right side a nonnegative number of letters from $RDVRK$ and in between two letters $A$ a positive number of letters from $RDVRK$.

Comment: For Stars and Bars, see [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/)
and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: For the 1st part of the problem, as you apparently discovered, $(8!)$ is wrong, because of the overcounting, since you have $3$ A's and $2$ R's.  With the A's separated, you still have to be careful about considering what happens if the $2$ R's end up in the same *section*.

Comment: @NicoTripeny- I used the n!/p!r!m!... method for getting the answer for the first part of the question. I took 9C3 as the selection of places where I can place 3 A's between the letters and multiplied with 5!/2! which is the permutation of  5 letters omitting the A.

Comment: @Henry- My answer for the first part is 28x5!, I multiplied 9C3 with 5!/2!.

Comment: @user2661923- I didn't get 8! as the answer for the first part. I got 8!/3!x2! which will equal to 28x5!

Comment: You misinterpreted my comment.  $(8!)$ is the *starter enumeration* that requires an **over-counting adjustment denominator** to compensate for having $3$ A's and $2$ R's.

Comment: @user2661923- I couldn't get what you are actually trying to say.

Comment: @DanielJoseph It might help to instead calculate the number of permutations with consecutive As. Then subtract from the first answer. That may be an easier way to think about it.

Comment: @DanielJoseph It is really better for you to publish at least your answer on the first question by means of an edit of your question. This to avoid closing and/or downvoting and avoiding to receive useless comments.

Comment: @Vera- I published my answer to the first part.

Comment: Going forward, please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to express the Math.  I agree with your first answer of $$\frac{8!}{(2!) \times (3!)}.$$  Notice that the denominator contains a factor that compensates for $2$ R's and a factor that compensates for $3$ A's.  This is what I was referring to, by the phrase **over counting adjustment denominator.**

Comment: @user2661923- Ok, And about the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In how many permutations of the letters of the word AARDVARK are the As separated?

We will first arrange the five letters D, K, R, R, V.  Choose two of the five positions for the Rs, then arrange the three distinct letters D, V, and K in the remaining three positions.  This can be done in
$$\binom{5}{2}3! = \frac{5!}{2!3!} \cdot 3! = \frac{5!}{2!}$$
ways.  The factor of $2!$ in the denominator accounts for the number of ways the two Rs can be permuted among themselves within a given arrangement without producing an arrangement distinct from the given arrangement.

For each such arrangement, there are now six spaces in which we can place the three As.
$$\square L_1 \square L_2 \square L_3 \square L_4 \square L_5 \square$$
To separate the three As, we must select three of these six spaces in which to place an A, which can be done in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways.

Hence, the number of arrangements of the letters of the word AARDVARK in which the three As are separated is
$$\binom{5}{2}3!\binom{6}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks man, I understood it.